# collection of derivative nouns

Tags: etymology, computational-linguistics, reference-request, linguistic-typology, nouns

I am a researcher in Computational Linguistics. Recently, my research interests led me towards the analysis derivative nouns, specifically nouns derived from other nouns. For example, `India to Indian, Grammar to grammarian` but not `drive to driver`.

I got to read literature that suggests the relationship between affixes and semantic senses that leads to derivation of derivative nouns. A sense can have multiple affixes (American, Delhite etc.) . Also an affix can cater to multiple senses (Grammarian, Orwelian, Australian).

I am interested in finding ways where I can find pair of words which follow such relations and filter them from the `False cognate`. But in order to do this I would require **resources that tells me possible pairs of those words and if possible the list of affixes that can be used**.

**If I can be pointed to any digital resource regarding the word etymology of derivative nouns** then I can formulate the problem. Kindly pardon me, If I am not following the community guidelines as I am not familiar with the community as such. I am looking for resources in English , French or German.